# UnicodeをURLエンコードした文字列を表示したとき、変換後の文字列をコピーできない場合がある

Tags: emeditor

UnicodeでURLエンコードした文字列を編集しています。

EmEditorは読みたい部分にマウスカーソルを持って行くと
URLデコードが自動的にされ、ポップアップウィンドウに
URLデコード変換後の文字列が表示されます。

ポップアップウィンドウの下部には、"コピー" "変換"
"すぺて変換" "すべて無効"のリンクが表示されるはずですが
マウスカーソルを動かしていくと、"コピー" "変換"等の
リンクが表示されないため、複写が出来ない場合があります。

**追記**
マウスカーソルを動かしていくと...

・ポップアップウィンドウの下部に HTMLのタグらしき
　ものが表示されます。

・"コピー" "変換" "すぺて変換" "すべて無効"のリンクが
　表示されない場合がある。

といった現象も確認いたしました。

Version 20.5.1 を利用しています。EmEditor Pro の設定はレジストリに保存。

[image: ポップアップウインドウの表示がおかしい01]
[image: ポップアップウインドウの表示がおかしい02]

%u3000%u543E%u8F29%u308F%u304C%u306F%u3044%u306F%u732B%u3067%u3042%u308B%u3002%u540D%u524D%u306F%u307E%u3060%u7121%u3044%u3002%0A%u3000%u3069%u3053%u3067%u751F%u308C%u305F%u304B%u3068%u3093%u3068%u898B%u5F53%u3051%u3093%u3068%u3046%u304C%u3064%u304B%u306C%u3002%u4F55%u3067%u3082%u8584%u6697%u3044%u3058%u3081%u3058%u3081%u3057%u305F%u6240%u3067%u30CB%u30E3%u30FC%u30CB%u30E3%u30FC%u6CE3%u3044%u3066%u3044%u305F%u4E8B%u3060%u3051%u306F%u8A18%u61B6%u3057%u3066%u3044%u308B%u3002%u543E%u8F29%u306F%u3053%u3053%u3067%u59CB%u3081%u3066%u4EBA%u9593%u3068%u3044%u3046%u3082%u306E%u3092%u898B%u305F%u3002%u3057%u304B%u3082%u3042%u3068%u3067%u805E%u304F%u3068%u305D%u308C%u306F%u66F8%u751F%u3068%u3044%u3046%u4EBA%u9593%u4E2D%u3067%u4E00%u756A%u7370%u60AA%u3069%u3046%u3042%u304F%u306A%u7A2E%u65CF%u3067%u3042%u3063%u305F%u305D%u3046%u3060%u3002%u3053%u306E%u66F8%u751F%u3068%u3044%u3046%u306E%u306F%u6642%u3005%u6211%u3005%u3092%u6355%u3064%u304B%u307E%u3048%u3066%u716E%u306B%u3066%u98DF%u3046%u3068%u3044%u3046%u8A71%u3067%u3042%u308B%u3002%u3057%u304B%u3057%u305D%u306E%u5F53%u6642%u306F%u4F55%u3068%u3044%u3046%u8003%u3082%u306A%u304B%u3063%u305F%u304B%u3089%u5225%u6BB5%u6050%u3057%u3044%u3068%u3082%u601D%u308F%u306A%u304B%u3063%u305F%u3002%u305F%u3060%u5F7C%u306E%u638C%u3066%u306E%u3072%u3089%u306B%u8F09%u305B%u3089%u308C%u3066%u30B9%u30FC%u3068%u6301%u3061%u4E0A%u3052%u3089%u308C%u305F%u6642%u4F55%u3060%u304B%u30D5%u30EF%u30D5%u30EF%u3057%u305F%u611F%u3058%u304C%u3042%u3063%u305F%u3070%u304B%u308A%u3067%u3042%u308B%u3002%u638C%u306E%u4E0A%u3067%u5C11%u3057%u843D%u3061%u3064%u3044%u3066%u66F8%u751F%u306E%u9854%u3092%u898B%u305F%u306E%u304C%u3044%u308F%u3086%u308B%u4EBA%u9593%u3068%u3044%u3046%u3082%u306E%u306E%u898B%u59CB%u307F%u306F%u3058%u3081%u3067%u3042%u308D%u3046%u3002%u3053%u306E%u6642%u5999%u306A%u3082%u306E%u3060%u3068%u601D%u3063%u305F%u611F%u3058%u304C%u4ECA%u3067%u3082%u6B8B%u3063%u3066%u3044%u308B%u3002%u7B2C%u4E00%u6BDB%u3092%u3082%u3063%u3066%u88C5%u98FE%u3055%u308C%u3079%u304D%u306F%u305A%u306E%u9854%u304C%u3064%u308B%u3064%u308B%u3057%u3066%u307E%u308B%u3067%u85AC%u7F36%u3084%u304B%u3093%u3060%u3002%u305D%u306E%u5F8C%u3054%u732B%u306B%u3082%u3060%u3044%u3076%u9022%u3042%u3063%u305F%u304C%u3053%u3093%u306A%u7247%u8F2A%u304B%u305F%u308F%u306B%u306F%u4E00%u5EA6%u3082%u51FA%u4F1A%u3067%u304F%u308F%u3057%u305F%u4E8B%u304C%u306A%u3044%u3002%u306E%u307F%u306A%u3089%u305A%u9854%u306E%u771F%u4E2D%u304C%u3042%u307E%u308A%u306B%u7A81%u8D77%u3057%u3066%u3044%u308B%u3002%u305D%u3046%u3057%u3066%u305D%u306E%u7A74%u306E%u4E2D%u304B%u3089%u6642%u3005%u3077%u3046%u3077%u3046%u3068%u7159%u3051%u3080%u308A%u3092%u5439%u304F%u3002%u3069%u3046%u3082%u54BD%u3080%u305B%u307D%u304F%u3066%u5B9F%u306B%u5F31%u3063%u305F%u3002%u3053%u308C%u304C%u4EBA%u9593%u306E%u98F2%u3080%u7159%u8349%u305F%u3070%u3053%u3068%u3044%u3046%u3082%u306E%u3067%u3042%u308B%u4E8B%u306F%u3088%u3046%u3084%u304F%u3053%u306E%u9803%u77E5%u3063%u305F%u3002%0A%u3000%u3053%u306E%u66F8%u751F%u306E%u638C%u306E%u88CF%u3046%u3061%u3067%u3057%u3070%u3089%u304F%u306F%u3088%u3044%u5FC3%u6301%u306B%u5750%u3063%u3066%u304A%u3063%u305F%u304C%u3001%u3057%u3070%u3089%u304F%u3059%u308B%u3068%u975E%u5E38%u306A%u901F%u529B%u3067%u904B%u8EE2%u3057%u59CB%u3081%u305F%u3002%u66F8%u751F%u304C%u52D5%u304F%u306E%u304B%u81EA%u5206%u3060%u3051%u304C%u52D5%u304F%u306E%u304B%u5206%u3089%u306A%u3044%u304C%u7121%u6697%u3080%u3084%u307F%u306B%u773C%u304C%u5EFB%u308B%u3002%u80F8%u304C%u60AA%u304F%u306A%u308B%u3002%u5230%u5E95%u3068%u3046%u3066%u3044%u52A9%u304B%u3089%u306A%u3044%u3068%u601D%u3063%u3066%u3044%u308B%u3068%u3001%u3069%u3055%u308A%u3068%u97F3%u304C%u3057%u3066%u773C%u304B%u3089%u706B%u304C%u51FA%u305F%u3002%u305D%u308C%u307E%u3067%u306F%u8A18%u61B6%u3057%u3066%u3044%u308B%u304C%u3042%u3068%u306F%u4F55%u306E%u4E8B%u3084%u3089%u3044%u304F%u3089%u8003%u3048%u51FA%u305D%u3046%u3068%u3057%u3066%u3082%u5206%u3089%u306A%u3044%u3002%0A%u3000%u3075%u3068%u6C17%u304C%u4ED8%u3044%u3066%u898B%u308B%u3068%u66F8%u751F%u306F%u3044%u306A%u3044%u3002%u305F%u304F%u3055%u3093%u304A%u3063%u305F%u5144%u5F1F%u304C%u4E00%u758B%u3074%u304D%u3082%u898B%u3048%u306C%u3002%u809D%u5FC3%u304B%u3093%u3058%u3093%u306E%u6BCD%u89AA%u3055%u3048%u59FF%u3092%u96A0%u3057%u3066%u3057%u307E%u3063%u305F%u3002%u305D%u306E%u4E0A%u4ECA%u3044%u307E%u307E%u3067%u306E%u6240%u3068%u306F%u9055%u3063%u3066%u7121%u6697%u3080%u3084%u307F%u306B%u660E%u308B%u3044%u3002%u773C%u3092%u660E%u3044%u3066%u3044%u3089%u308C%u306C%u304F%u3089%u3044%u3060%u3002%u306F%u3066%u306A%u4F55%u3067%u3082%u5BB9%u5B50%u3088%u3046%u3059%u304C%u304A%u304B%u3057%u3044%u3068%u3001%u306E%u305D%u306E%u305D%u9019%u306F%u3044%u51FA%u3057%u3066%u898B%u308B%u3068%u975E%u5E38%u306B%u75DB%u3044%u3002%u543E%u8F29%u306F%u85C1%u308F%u3089%u306E%u4E0A%u304B%u3089%u6025%u306B%u7B39%u539F%u306E%u4E2D%u3078%u68C4%u3066%u3089%u308C%u305F%u306E%u3067%u3042%u308B%u3002

Answer (score 1):

まもなく公開する v20.5.2 では、ある程度の修正をしています。ただし、カーソル位置より前後に 約 65535 文字を超える非常に長い文章の場合には、コピーまたは変換後の文字列が切り詰められてしまいます。これは、あまり長い文字列を処理しようとすると全体的に動作が遅くなってしまうためです。

長い文書の場合は、ツール チップを使用するのではなく、<kbd>Ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>A</kbd> で全文書を選択した後、`編集` メニューの `選択範囲のエンコード/デコード` - `Universal Character Names を Unicode に変換` コマンドを使用することをおすすめします。